# Rails: ActiveRecord interdependent attributes setters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In activerecord, attribute setters seems to be called in order of the param hash.
Therefore, in the following sample, "par_prio" will be empty in "par1" setter.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def par1=(value)
    Rails.logger.info("second param: #{self.par_prio}")
    super(value)
  end
end

MyModel.new({ :par1 => 'bla', :par_prio => 'bouh' })
```

Is there any way to simply define an order on attributes in the model ?

Comment: in fact, the only way to do this in a good way would be to add an ordered feature on attr_accessible

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I have a solution, but not "generic", by overriding the initialize method on "MyModel":

```
def initialize(attributes = {}, options = {})
  if attributes[:par_prio]
    value = attributes.delete(:par_prio)
    attributes = { :par_prio => value }.merge(attributes)
  end
  super(attributes, options)
end
```

Moreover, it does not works if par_prio is another model that has a relation on, and is used to build MyModel:

```
class ParPrio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many my_models
end

par_prio = ParPrio.create
par_prio.my_models.build(:par1 => 'blah')
```

The par_prio param will not be available in the initialize override.

Answer (score 0):

Override assign_attributes on the specific model where you need the assignments to happen in a specific order:

```
    attr_accessor :first_attr  # Attr that needs to be assigned first
    attr_accessor :second_attr # Attr that needs to be assigned second

    def assign_attributes(new_attributes, options = {})
      sorted_new_attributes = new_attributes.with_indifferent_access
      if sorted_new_attributes.has_key?(:second_attr)
        first_attr_val = sorted_new_attributes.delete :first_attr
        raise ArgumentError.new('YourModel#assign_attributes :: second_attr assigned without first_attr') unless first_attr_val.present?
        new_attributes = Hash[:first_attr, first_attr_val].merge(sorted_new_attributes)
      end
      super(new_attributes, options = {})
    end
```